# SQL statement in for loop only updating once

Tags: asp-classic, vbscript

```
if request.form("submitChange") = "site" then
    for i = 0 to UBound(arrmode)
        SQLstr = "UPDATE SCSer SET Ser_Site_Num = '" & request.form("site_to") & "' WHERE Ser_Num = '" & arrmode(i) & "'"
        conn.execute(SQLstr)
        Response.Write("SUCCESSFULLY UPDATED! " + arrmode(i))
    next
end if
```

Comment: Check value of UBound(arrmode). See if it makes sense.

Comment: If this is connecting to SQL Server, see [Bobby Tables](bobby-tables.com).  If Access, then never mind.

Comment: You need to provide more information than this. Does `arrmode` actually contain more than one value? Is there an `On Error Resume Next` in your code?

Comment: The loop does display the right values in arrmode when it loops through. Its just the SQL statement not running the right amount (only running once) when its looped.

Comment: Heres a link to another post same qn with more info http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16956554/loop-update-statement-in-classic-asp