# loop update statement in classic asp

Tags: sql, loops, asp-classic

I really need some help with this code. The loop is only making the update statement run once when there are maybe 4 records chosen so it has to loop 4 times. This is the 1st time ive come across this problem and I cant seem to see why it is doing it like that. Please help. Thank you.

```
<!--#include file="connectionString.inc"-->
<%
Dim strmode, arrmode,i,rs,SQLstr, a, b, site_to


strmode=Request.form("changeBox")
cont1=request.form("cont1")
arrmode=split(strmode,",")




if request.form("submitChange") = "" then
    response.write("Please try again, you have no selected anything. Press back on your browser")
end if
   if request.form("submitChange") = "site" then
    response.write(b)
    for i = 0 to UBound(arrmode)
        SQLstr = "UPDATE SCSer SET Ser_Site_Num = '" & request.form("site_to") & "' WHERE Ser_Num = '" & arrmode(i) & "'"
        Set rs = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
        rs.open SQLstr, conn, 1, 2       
        Response.Write("SUCCESSFULLY UPDATED! " + arrmode(i))
    next
end if

if request.form("submitChange") = "contract" then
    a=LBound(arrmode)
b=UBound(arrmode)
    SQLstr = "UPDATE SCSer SET Ser_Site_Num = '" & request.form("site_to") & "' WHERE Ser_Num BETWEEN '" & arrmode(a) & "' AND '" & arrmode(b) & "'"
    Set rs = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
    rs.open SQLstr, conn, 1, 2
    Response.Write("SUCCESSFULLY UPDATED! <br/>")
    response.write(arrmode(a)+"<br/>")
    response.write(arrmode(b))
end if
%>
```

Comment: Are you sure that arrmode actually has more than 1 records? What does UBound(arrmode) return?
BTW this kind of code is just asking for a dependency injection attack. ADO supports parameterized queries. They are safer, faster, and easier to write

Comment: Hi UBound(arrmode) returns the number of records stored in the array. I dont know what dependency injection attack is and i dont know how to do the ADO bit. Can you help me please?

Comment: What is the value of UBound(arrmode)? I'll bet it's 1 instead of what you think. Just do a Response.Write, or better yet, debug the application to see what arrmode contains

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos

when i select 3 records, ubound(arrmode) says 2 so it is correct it is looping 3 times but the sql statement is running once. Ive changed the code slightly instead of running it directly from the connection string im running it through ADO below is the current code

Comment: what are the data types of `Ser_Site_Num` and `Ser_Num` ? (You can edit your question to update the code to what you are using now, instead of using the comments section)

Comment: ser num and ser site num are both varchars

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this and see what the response says:

```
<%
Dim strmode, arrmode,i,rs,SQLstr, a, b, site_to
Dim oConn

strmode=Request.form("changeBox")
cont1=request.form("cont1")
arrmode=split(strmode,",")

Response.Write "submitChange is:" & request.form("submitChange") & "<br>"


if request.form("submitChange") = "" then
    response.write("Please try again, you have not selected anything. Press back on your browser")
    Response.end
end if

set oConn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
oConn.Open conn

if request.form("submitChange") = "site" then
    for i = 0 to UBound(arrmode)
        SQLstr = "UPDATE SCSer SET Ser_Site_Num = '" & request.form("site_to") & "' WHERE Ser_Num = '" & Trim(arrmode(i)) & "'"
        Response.Write "Executing SQL: "& SQLstr &"<br>"
        oConn.Execute(SQLstr)      
        Response.Write("SUCCESSFULLY UPDATED! " + arrmode(i))
    next
end if

if request.form("submitChange") = "contract" then
    a=LBound(arrmode)
    b=UBound(arrmode)
    SQLstr = "UPDATE SCSer SET Ser_Site_Num = '" & request.form("site_to") & "' WHERE convert(int,Ser_Num) BETWEEN " & arrmode(a) & " AND " & arrmode(b) & ""
    Response.Write "Executing SQL: "& SQLstr &"<br>"
    oConn.Execute(SQLstr)    
    Response.Write("SUCCESSFULLY UPDATED! <br/>")
    response.write(arrmode(a)+"<br/>")
    response.write(arrmode(b))
end if
%>
```

Comment: This is what it says:

submitChange is:site
Executing SQL: UPDATE SCSer SET Ser_Site_Num = 'sungard03' WHERE Ser_Num = '53852'
An error occurred on the server when processing the URL. Please contact the system administrator.
If you are the system administrator please click here to find out more about this error.

Comment: have changed the code , i think `conn` is a connection string

Comment: ive tried it again and here is the output

submitChange is:site
Executing SQL: UPDATE SCSer SET Ser_Site_Num = 'sungard03' WHERE Ser_Num = '53852'
SUCCESSFULLY UPDATED! 53852Executing SQL: UPDATE SCSer SET Ser_Site_Num = 'sungard03' WHERE Ser_Num = ' 53853'
SUCCESSFULLY UPDATED! 53853Executing SQL: UPDATE SCSer SET Ser_Site_Num = 'sungard03' WHERE Ser_Num = ' 53854'
SUCCESSFULLY UPDATED! 53854Executing SQL: UPDATE SCSer SET Ser_Site_Num = 'sungard03' WHERE Ser_Num = ' 53855'
SUCCESSFULLY UPDATED! 53855

Comment: Even though that is the output, the other records still show they havent been updated but only the 1st one is.

Comment: All your "Ser_Site_Num" will be updated to "sungard03"; is that what you wanted ?

Comment: because it dissapears off the list, i then do a search and it appears with the new site number

Comment: You have space in front of the array values. Try this:`SQLstr = "UPDATE SCSer SET Ser_Site_Num = '" & request.form("site_to") & "' WHERE Ser_Num = '" & trim(arrmode(i)) & "'"`

Comment: :) . You could mark my post as accepted and close. The problem was that   `Request.form("changeBox")` had a comma-space delimited list and you were splitting using comma,which leaves a space there.